# Papers in algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am an undergraduate student, I have a decent background in algebraic topology, I have studied Munkres and Armstrong. I am planning to pursue research in algebraic topology and would like a list of published papers preferably in ascending order of complexity, to go through in these summers.

Comment: That's pretty ambitious. When I asked a similar question in my first year of grad school, a professor recommended I read Eilenberg-Mac Lane's [paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2372628?uid=3739664&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102347264087) on acyclic models.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you meant Armstrong's "Basic Topology" and Munkres "Topology" ? If so, I would recommend studying standard texts at least a little bit longer before tackling research papers. You really should aim to understand most of [Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) first in my opinion.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebraic_Topology.html?id=4hE7AAAAIAAJ

Answer (score 5):

What about "Handbook of Algebraic Topology" by I.M James? 
The book description:

"Algebraic topology (also known as homotopy theory) is a flourishing branch of modern mathematics. It is very much an international subject and this is reflected in the background of the 36 leading experts who have contributed to the Handbook. Written for the reader who already has a grounding in the subject, the volume consists of 27 expository surveys covering the most active areas of research. They provide the researcher with an up-to-date overview of this exciting branch of mathematics."

Answer (score 0):

A natural progression from Algebraic Topology is Topological K-Theory, if you have already seen some of this stuff, then some great applications of algebraic topology are seen in the papers by Adams, particular paper IV.